How to solve the Shift/Reduce conflict in my CUP grammar for boolean expressions?
I'm not a specialist in grammar, and I encounter a problem I haven't been able to solve or find answers to in the questions.
I have written a parser for boolean expressions. So far, it works like a charm, except for one rule : I'd like to write negative boolean variables like this: ~a, and positive variables just "a". So these are the relevant (I hope) parts of my CUP code:
terminal String IDVAR;

non terminal PropositionalFormula PROP_FORMULA, PROP_VARIABLE;

precedence left NOT;

PROP_FORMULA     ::= PROP_VARIABLE:v
                 {: RESULT = v; :}
                 | PROP_NEGATION:n
                 {: RESULT = n; :}
                 | ...

PROP_VARIABLE    ::= IDVAR:n
                 {: RESULT = new PropositionalAtom(n,"+"); :}
                 | NOT IDVAR:n
                 {: RESULT = new PropositionalAtom(n,"-"); :}
                 ;

PROP_NEGATION    ::= NOT PROP_FORMULA:f
                 {: RESULT = new PropositionalNegation(f); :}
                 ;
                 .
                 .
                 .

If I embrace "NOT IDVAR:n" with "LPAREN/RPAREN", there is no conflict, but it forces me to embrace all my negated variables with parenthesis. Without the PARENs, there is a shift/reduce conflict, and I think it doesn't choose the correct production.
Testing the PAREN version shows me that when I have a "~a" in my code, the PROP_NEGATION rule is used instead of the PROP_VARIABLE rule. So I have to augment the priority of the PROP_VARIABLE rule, but don't know how to do it...
Is there a simple way to solve this problem?
